# How to get IPv6 ip from the router, what is my subnet mask?

Tags: networking, 16.04, router, ipv6, ipv4

This is the router asking to put an address but when i insert 192.168.0.2 it fails what is the IPv6 value for that to setup in the router? So that i get proper IPv6 in Ubuntu?

[image]

In Ubuntu from the Router using  DHCP i want to get IPv6 IP (192.168.0.2), Subnet mask 255.255.255.0)

Comment: Does your ISP supports IPv6 ? Do you want to use IPv6 instead of IPv4 only?

Comment: I dont want to use anymore IPv4 in my INTRANET and Ubuntu because my clients are all moved to IPv6 and causing me problem. (My ISP 1 supports IPv6  and my ISP 2 does not support IPv6. I have 2 ISP provider to choose which one i want to use.)

Comment: 192.168.0.2 and 255.255.255.0 are IPv4 format, IPv6 address might look like:  2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370:7334 (similar to the Address : FE80::52C7 in the attached screen-shot)

Comment: Correct, so i try to insert the value `2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370:7334` there right? or is it cause you dont use 0 to short it no?
 `2001:db8:85a3:::8a2e:370:7334`

Comment: I'd start with the IPv6 address mentioned in your screen-shot (FE80::52C7....)

Comment: What does the `FE80::52C7:BFFF:FE51:8BCE` stands for if you convert the hexadecimal value is it something like 192.168.0.1?

Comment: assuming that your router is set to IPv6, what is the result of `ifconfig` on your ubuntu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56638/discussion-between-yaron-and-yumyumyum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SLAAC+Sateless DHCP` and do not switch of DHCPv4, else many devices wont be even get IPv4 nor IPv6